# Transform lookup library

Tags: c, perl, transform

I have two 32bit vectors one derived from other by mathematical/logical transform.
Is there a Perl/C library which can look up what kind of transform(Or list of all possible transforms that library is capable of inferring) has been applied ?

```
Case1. 968eac37 -> 968eac37  
Case2. 12345678 -> 23456781 
Case3. 614e1973 -> 30f7150d

Output
1. No transform
2. Bit wise shift left 4 or trivial addition
3. Trivial subtraction or something else or unknown
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this would involve actually *applying* all the transforms to check the results.  Any transform that involved encryption would be *by definition* not determinable.

Take the case of "trivial subtraction".  How would you distinguish that from "trivial addition/multiplication modulo 32 bits"?

Your underlying question is really "how do I undo encryption", which for any sufficiently strong encryption is impossible.  For "weak" encryptions there can be multiple answers, so there is no such library.

Comment: I came across this problem while debugging hardware - where one vector got transformed to another (erroneously) usually because the data path was wired incorrectly. What if I restrict to simple logical transform operations ? Like shifting bits,reverse bits etc ?

Comment: Given any two random 32-bit strings I can easily come up with any number of sets of logical operations that transforms one into the other. For example, given two random bit-srings, A and B, calculate C = (A xor B).  Now (C xor A) produces B and (C xor B) produces A.  This can be done for ANY two bit-strings of the same length.